# Running wmi process remotely, doesnt have proper domain user privileges

Tags: windows, permissions, active-directory, wmi, privileges

i need to run a WMI script, to create a process on a remote with specific privileges (in a domain).

The scenario is as the following:
Computer `A` with domain user `a`
Computer `B` with domain user `b`
Computer `C` with domain user `c`
Domain admin user, called `administrator`

from computer `A`, im running runas.exe, and creating a new CMD prompt  with `administrator` account privileges.

from this command prompt, im running a VBS script to create a remote process on computer `B` (successfully).

Within the new process on computer `B` im trying to access directories on both computer `A` and `C`. both result in `Access denied (5)`.

when im running on computer `B` runas, using the `administrator` privileges, i do have the access to other computer, and the domain admin privileges, but when the process is ran from WMI i dont.

If i am running cmd.exe, and i type `whoami`, i get `DOMAIN_NAME\Administrator`, so i know for sure i am running in the domain admin privileges.

Does anyone have an idea of what the reason for this might be?

Answer (score 0):

because i am running from session 0 i dont have premissions to access other computers (some kind of protection mechanism?)

Running in the context of user session (\ session 1 mostly) will fix the authentication problem